# List model field Django?

Tags: django, django-models, view

I just recently started working on a planner app using Django. I made a new User class that extends Django's User class. This is the code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    projects = []
```

The projects list is for all the projects the User has. Below is the model for Project and the view this is used in:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=60)

def dashboard_view(request, *args, **kwargs):  
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        context = {
        'projects' : request.user.projects
    }
        return render(request, 'dash.html', context)
    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

This works temporarily, but when I end the server, it turns back into an empty list. Is there any equivalent for this in the form of a model field type? Thanks guys!

Comment: You are looking for either a ForeignKey or a JSON field but I think a ForeignKey will do here. Add a field `user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel...)` to your Project model and save the user. There are like a hundred  tutorials out there on ForeignKeys and how to use them. Pick any.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better method. In your project model, you can add a field like

```
from django.conf import settings
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,...)
```

And in your view, you can use something like

```
request.user.project_set.all()
```

this gives you access to all projects for the logged in user.